# ruby on rails ignores my form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written in my index.html.erb the following lines

```
<% form_tag illnesses_path, :method =>'get' do %>
  <p>
     <%=  text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
     <%=  submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

expecting that it will write a form element but rails completrly neglected those line.
when I wrote

```
 <p>
     <%=  text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
     <%=  submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
```

the items apeared (but no form element).
Why was the form element neglected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change 
`<% form_tag illnesses_path, :method =>'get' do %>`

to

`<%= form_tag illnesses_path, :method =>'get' do %>`.

Comment: Wow. works. I wonder why is it that in all the documentations it is written without the = sign ?

Comment: in rdoc? it's documented without any tags. If you're not seeing something you should see in your views, you are probably missing the output tags. That's the first thing to check.

Comment: the reason you see it in documentation that way is because originally form tags were written in irb that way, I believe that changed when Rails 2.0 was released.  Be sure you're looking at up to date documentation, Rails changes fast.